# Variables not being destroyed with each iteration of a while loop?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int main()
{
  while (1)
  {
    FILE *fptr1;
    char filename[100];
    printf("Enter the filename to open for reading \n");
    scanf("%s", filename); 
    fptr1 = fopen(filename, "r");

    int c, nl, nw, nc, state; // These variables aren't being reset.

    while ((c = fgetc(fptr1)) != EOF) 
    {
      ++nc;
      if (c == '\n') ++nl;
      if (c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == ' ') state = OUT;
      else if (state == OUT)
      {
        state = IN;
        ++nw;
      }
    };
    printf("Lines: %d Words: %d Characters: %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This is a simple program to parse a file and output how many lines, words, and characters it has. nl, nw, nc are incremented when new lines, words, and characters are detected. The output:

> Enter the filename to open for reading
>
> data.txt
>
> Lines: 6 Words: 15 Characters: 81
>
> Enter the filename to open for reading
>
> data.txt
>
> Lines: 12 Words: 30 Characters: 162
>
> Enter the filename to open for reading

It works correctly the first time, but it doesn't destroy nl, nw, nc when the while loop finishes and just keeps adding to them. Why?

Comment: Where's your `fclose()`?

Comment: What makes you think they should be "reset"? Local variables do not reset themselves, ever. It is you who are supposed to reset them. And you are not doing that. Uninitialized variables contain unpredictable values. These unpredictable might easily be values from the previous iteration. Or something else.

Comment: Heh.  Perhaps he's a convert from Java, where initialization to zero is provided.

Comment: That, and initializing to zero seemed to be reliable behavior in the other C programs I tried. Oops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking undefined behavior by accessing the unintialized variable.

And at each iteration their a new set of variables you get. That means you can't rely on the variable values from the previous iteration.

```
int c, nl = 0, nw = 0, nc = 0, state = OUT;
```

Few other notes change `scanf` to `scanf("%99s",filename);`.

Also close the file once you are done working with it. Otherwise if you use too many files without closing them you may run out of resources.

`flocse(fptr1);`

In this case even if you don't close it it will be closed upon exiting the process but still it is a good habit to deallocate resources that you use. It's *good practice*.

Comment: "*It's good practice*" It is indeed, it's like eating and not washing the dishes. It doesn't appear to matter but it's so annoying!

Answer (score 1):

You were "*lucky*" that it ever worked, you have to initialize them all

```
nl = nw = nc = state = 0;
```

right after their declaration perhaps. The important thing is that they must be initialized before the inner `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

> These variables aren't being reset.

In every iteration of `while` loop you need to reset them manually before using them, like this:

```
c = 0; 
nl = 0; 
nw = 0; 
nc = 0; 
state = OUT;
```

Also, make sure to close the file you are opening in every iteration of loop -

```
fclose(fptr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works because you're lucky that it doesn't crash. You have never initialized their values, so at each loop their value is resetted to **indeterminate**. Fortunately they're just the value from the last loop, but **no one guarantees this**.

There's also a potential leak that, you have never closed your file handles with `fclose(fptr1)`. Within a few loops you may start getting corrupted files or failure to open any more files.

Answer (score 0):

you have several issues in this piece of code. 
First of all, all your counters have no initial values. `nl, nw, nc, and state` could have any random value before the internal loop starts. They are allocated on stack and 'c' language does not initialize them for you. You'd been really lucky that it worked the first time around. So, you need to initialize them to '0', as shown int other answers.

But you have more issues there as well. First, your `scanf` does not check the size of the input. You assumed that the length of the file name cannot be longer than 100, however in reality it is not necessarily true. So, you need to use `%99s` or similar to make sure that the array is not overflown.

Secondly, you open the file at the beginning of the first lop and never close it, you need to do it at the end of the loop to free the resources, otherwise you risk to use up all system resources for opened files.